# "web_accessible_resources" works on one site but not another

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

So im getting the classic "Resources must be listed in the web_accessible_resources manifest key in order to be loaded by pages outside the extension." error in the console. The problem is that I believe it is actually properly listed, since it works everywhere, except this site for some reason: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/InventivetalentDev/minecraft-assets/1.18.2/assets/minecraft/textures/block/dirt.png

Here are the relating parts of my files (I am using manifest v3):

**manifest.json**

```
    "web_accessible_resources": [
        {
          "resources": ["content.css", "sprite.svg"],
          "matches": ["<all_urls>"]
        }
    ],
    "content_scripts":
    [{
          "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
          "js": ["content-script.js"],
          "run_at": "document_start"
    }]
```

**content-script.js**

```
function injectCSS() {
  const link = newElement('link');
  const head = $('head');
  link.rel = 'stylesheet';
  link.type = "text/css"
  link.href = chrome.runtime.getURL('content.css');
  head.appendChild(link);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, for anyone findig this question while looking for a solution for this problem in the future:

The reason this happens is that this site has a strict content policy, disallowing all resources (e.g. image or stylesheet) coming outside itself.
There are 3 ways to solve this issue, but only for stylesheets. For images, use BASE64 encoding. For SVGs, create them dinamically through JS.

**1. Easy and quick solution**

- Use this method only if you want to load a stylesheet (.css) every time, and only on the few specified websites in manifest.json!

*manifest.json*

> ```
> "content_scripts":[
>  {
>    "js": ["content-script.js"],
>    "css": ["style.css"],
>    "matches": ["https://stackoverflow.com/*"]
>  }
>  ]
> ```

**2. A hacky workaround I've learned from scripts**

- This method allows you to inject stylesheets without specifying anything in the manifest.json

*content-script.js*

> ```
> window.addEventListener('load', function() {
>    injectCSS();
> })
>
> function injectCSS() {
>   const style = document.createElement('style');
>   const head = document.querySelector('head');
>   style.rel = 'stylesheet';
>   style.type = "text/css"
>   style.textContent = css;
>   head.appendChild(style);
> }
>
> const css = `
> ::-webkit-scrollbar { 
>   display: none;
> }
> `
> ```

**3. The proper way to do it with Manifest V3**

*manifest.json*

```
"permissions": [
    "scripting"
],
"host_permissions": [
    "*://*/"
],
```

*content-script.js*

```
 window.addEventListener('load', function() {
    injectCSS();
 })
 
 function injectCSS() {
   chrome.runtime.sendMessage("injectCSS");
 }
```

*background.js*

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(message, sender, sendResponse) {
    if (message === "injectCSS") {
        chrome.scripting.insertCSS(
            {
                target: {tabId: sender.tab.id},
                files: ['style.css'],
            }
        )
    }
});
```